# How to Create a Wrapping Button in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, button

Requirements:

- Must support the MinWidth property
- Can display text on one or two lines only. Cannot wrap to 3 or more.
- Should make button as small as possible while respecting MinWidth
- Text can wrap only on spaces
- Cannot specify width. The button should keep growing horizontally.

Here is what I would like the buttons to look like (Ignore the styling please, the wrapping is the important part)

[image]

I am looking for ideas on how to make the text wrap dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have limited the text to two lines, my suggestion would be to write a custom panel as the button content which turns the specified text, font, etc. into a WPF FormattedText object.  You can then measure it and decide how you want it to layout and display in MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride.  FormattedText even has a parameter to display a ... abbreviation if the text doesn't fit.  To keep it to two lines, you would want to first create it, then check its Height to see what a single line is for height. (need to add rest in comments as StackOverflow is tossing errors).

Comment: You can then set its MaxTextWidth to the button width, then check the ft.Height again.  If it is more than 2x the original Height, you have more than 2 lines and want to set the MaxHeight to about 2x the original Height.

Comment: I will give that a shot and let you know how it works. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I've done almost this exact thing with it, so if it doesn't work for you let me know.  I just have to post in comments as SO today is tossing errors when I make anything but short posts.

Comment: I have the code working to split the string into the lines correctly but how did you handle displaying the newly split lines?

Comment: I wrote a simple custom panel.  In MeasureOverride, I used the size available to decide how to display the lines (single or double).  In ArrangeOverride I just placed them as they had been laid out in MeasureOverride (which modifies the FormattedText), but then centered the text.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to achieve this by editing the default template for `Button`, mainly adding a wrapping `TextBlock` instead of the default `ContentPresenter` and calculate its `Width` in a converter. This approach needed pretty much data in the converter though, there's proabaly easier (and better :) ways to do this but it seems to be working anyway. It needs a reference to **PresentationFramework.Aero** because of the `ButtonChrome` in the default template

Just use it like this

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource WrappingButton}"
        MinWidth="100"
        Content="This button has some long text">
</Button>
```

[image]
*Screenshot sample with 3 `WrappingButtons` in a `StackPanel`*

**WrappingButton Style**

```
<Style x:Key="WrappingButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <local:WrappingButtonWidthConverter x:Key="WrappingButtonWidthConverter"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                               FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                               FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                               FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                               LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                              Path=Content}">
                        <TextBlock.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WrappingButtonWidthConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="FontFamily"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="FontStyle"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="FontWeight"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="FontStretch"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="FontSize"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="MinWidth"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Width>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**WrappingButtonWidthConverter**

```
public class WrappingButtonWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = values[0].ToString();
        FontFamily fontFamily = values[1] as FontFamily;
        FontStyle fontStyle = (FontStyle)values[2];
        FontWeight fontWeight = (FontWeight)values[3];
        FontStretch fontStretch = (FontStretch)values[4];
        double fontSize = (double)values[5];
        double minWidth = (double)values[6];

        string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {' '});
        double widthSum = 0.0;
        List<double> wordWidths = GetWordWidths(words, fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch, fontSize, out widthSum);

        double width = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; width < (widthSum / 2.0) && i < wordWidths.Count; i++)
        {
            width += wordWidths[i];
        }

        return minWidth > 0.0 ? Math.Max(minWidth, width) : width;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private List<double> GetWordWidths(string[] words,
                                       FontFamily fontFamily,
                                       FontStyle fontStyle,
                                       FontWeight fontWeight,
                                       FontStretch fontStretch,
                                       double fontSize,
                                       out double widthSum)
    {
        List<double> wordWidths = new List<double>();
        widthSum = 0.0;
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Typeface myTypeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
            FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(word + " ",
                                                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                                 FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                                 myTypeface,
                                                 fontSize,
                                                 Brushes.Black);
            wordWidths.Add(ft.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace);
            widthSum += ft.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;
        }
        return wordWidths;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/07/11/339-wrapping-a-buttons-text-content-to-multiple-lines/

this got it done for me.  Also this :

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:Questions x:Key="theQs"/>
        <Style x:Key="WrappingButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10">

            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

and this:

```
<Button Name="btnDef4" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource WrappingButton}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=LVQuestions, Path=SelectedItem.TheDefs[3].Deftext}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RichTextBox as the Content of your Button:

```
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            rtb.IsReadOnly = true;
            rtb.Focusable = false;
            rtb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            rtb.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            rtb.AppendText("This button has some long text.");
            myButton.Content = rtb;
```